# Giant/giant's/giants- which is the right choice in the given context?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Microsoft recently offered a position to a teenager looking for a job at the American **giant's**.

Microsoft recently offered a position to a teenager looking for a job at the American **giants**.

Microsoft recently offered a position to a teenager looking for a job at the American **giant**.

American giant here clearly means Microsoft, but which of the above sentences is actually grammatically correct? As a non-native speaker, my intuition tells me it's the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only correct answer is the third one.

*American **giant's*** is a possessive, meaning "belonging to the American giant."
This usage is *only* acceptable with "at" when we mean to refer to a specific location which belongs to the American giant, for example "looking for a job at the American giant's Seattle campus." Because this is not the structure of the sentence, this option is incorrect.

*American **giants*** is plural, meaning "two or more American giants." This is not correct; there is only one giant referenced in the sentence, namely Microsoft.

*American **giant*** correctly describes the corporation which has been mentioned earlier in the sentence.